# RollBack all executed query

Tags: c#, mysql, commit, rollback

How Can rollback all executed query on one transaction in MYSQL query that executed in C#

```
if (cn0.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) cn0.Open();
            cm0.Connection = cn0;
            cm0.CommandText = "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0 ";
            cm0.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cm0.CommandTimeout = 0;//unlimited

            tr = cn0.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
            cm0.Transaction = tr;

            try
            {
                cm0.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS i2019.Produkh LIKE i2019.karyawanh ";
                cm0.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cm0.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS i2019.Profileh LIKE i2019.karyawanh ";
                cm0.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cm0.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS i2019.Customerh LIKE i2019.karyawanh ";
                cm0.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cm0.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS i2019.supplierh LIKE i2019.karyawanh ";
                cm0.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cm0.CommandText = "INSERT INTO i2019.produkh (idx,idH,idb,Faktur,tglB,jmlB,ket,edit,bf,modifat) " +
                    "SELECT idx, idH, idb, Faktur, tglB, jmlB, ket, edit, bf, modifat FROM karyawanh.t1 WHERE jmlB < 0";
                                cm0.ExecuteNonQuery();

                tr.Commit();
                if (cn0.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) cn0.Close();
                tr.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                if (cn0.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) cn0.Close();
                tr.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
```

But ERROR when Execute query on the CREATE SUPPLIERH TABLE
so rollback and closing the connection.

and i hope
ALL Table :

- Produkh
- profileh
- customerh
- supplierh

is not created, because there is error on other

But Actually after rolled back
only the **supplierh** table is rolled back
and the other not rolled back.

please tell me how?

Comment: [Statements that cause an implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html)

Comment: where is statement that cannot rollback all executed query

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` is clearly mentioned in @Steve's link as a statement that causes an implicit `COMMIT`, meaning you cannot roll back. What is unclear about what that link explains? If you want to roll back, you have to `DROP` the tables yourself.

Comment: How the table is formed, before the COMMIT has not been implemented

Comment: Because of the **implicit** commit @AliMa'sum . `The statements listed in this section (and any synonyms for them) implicitly end any transaction active in the current session, as if you had done a COMMIT before executing the statement.` is literally the first sentence in that link.

Comment: Is there a faster strategy to handle error on implicit commit